# Error creating bean with name 'defaultTbMailConfigTemplateService' Thingsboard release-3.6

Tags: java, maven, javabeans, thingsboard

I have build thingsboard release-3.6 build from sources.
I am facing issue while running boot-jar file in application/target, receiving following error.

```
ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultTbMailConfigTemplateService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [templates/mail_config_templates.json] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/home/thingspad/Documents/thingsboard/application/target/thingsboard-3.6.1-SNAPSHOT-boot.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/templates/mail_config_templates.json
```

Maven Build of thingsboard has no issues, issue while starting the boot-jar file. [Error while running boot jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3Hy7.png).

can anyone help me out with the issue I am facing?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the below code in that. There is an issue with resolving the file path for the resource `templates/mail_config_templates.json`

```
@PostConstruct
private void postConstruct() throws IOException {
    mailConfigTemplates = JacksonUtil.toJsonNode(new ClassPathResource("/templates/mail_config_templates.json").getFile());
}
```

The file seems to be located inside a JAR file, and the application is unable to resolve its absolute file path because it's not directly accessible in the file system.

Here you can check potential solution:

```
@PostConstruct
private void postConstruct() throws IOException {
    try (InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/templates/mail_config_templates.json")) {
        if (inputStream == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found: mail_config_templates.json");
        }
        mailConfigTemplates = JacksonUtil.toJsonNode(new String(inputStream.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error loading mail configuration templates", e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```